# Using GDB: I crash (segfault). How can I see the lines of code leading up to it?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Forgive me if this is a duplicate - but I can't seem to find any straightforward advice on this.

I have an application that executes a loop a great many times.  At some some point, this segfaults.  It's written in C, I've been using GDB to debug this.  In the past I have been hitting n hundreds of times, and there is something to be said for this.  However, I think it would be VASTLY more efficient in the present case if I could actually step backwards to see where the fault happens.

Unfortunately,  library code is being cited in the crash (from a precompiled library if I recall correctly) so I can't even attempt to look at code going backwards.  Moreover, I trust this library.  (For now of course :P)

I would be immensely grateful if someone could provide a few ways to trace backwards to lines of code in my files where this crash happens!

Comment: google "gdb crash course" and/or "gdb tutorial"

Comment: use 'bt', short for backtrace - I often find this handy when diagnosing the cause of segfaults

Comment: You may find analyzing a run of your program with Valgrind to be a good complement to debugging with gdb.  Valgrind will probably give you a good idea of *what's* happening, and then you can focus with gdb on *why*.

Comment: What architecture and operating system? You may be able to use [rr](https://rr-project.org/) or gdb's [reverse execution](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Reverse-Execution.html).

Comment: @bph Thanks a lot, actually: backtrace did it

Answer (score 1):

> In the past I have been hitting n hundreds of times, and there is something to be said for this.

If your crash is repeatable (e.g. it *always* crashes after 1234-th call to `foo()`), then here is a useful technique to avoid hitting `n` hundreds of times:

```
(gdb) break foo
(gdb) ignore 1 10000
(gdb) run
```

At this point, your program runs and crashes on N-th call to `foo`. Use `info break` to find out what N is. And now:

```
(gdb) ignore 1 M  # where M == N-1
(gdb) run
```

Now you are stopped on penultimate call to `foo`. Step through your code, set breakpoints, etc. until you get to the next call to `foo` (which will crash).

> However, I think it would be VASTLY more efficient in the present case if I could actually step backwards to see where the fault happens.

On Linux you *could* do that: https://rr-project.org/